# Get content or excerpt of top rated votes @GD-Star Rating?

Tags: plugins, content, excerpt, plugin-gd-star-rating

I am using the GD-star Rating plugin and I have a function which outputs the top rated posts. The problem: it won't show the content or the excerpt of those posts. How can I do this? This is the function I am using:

```
<?php
global $wpdb; // include the $wpdb
$query= "SELECT p.ID, p.post_title as title, visitor_votes + user_votes as total_votes, visitor_votes, user_votes  FROM  `".$wpdb->prefix."gdsr_data_article` da INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON da.post_id = p.ID order by total_votes desc limit 20";
$results=$wpdb->get_results($query); // run the query on the database
if ($results) { // if we have any results
    ?>
    <table><thead><tr><th>Position</th><th>Post</th><th>Points</th></tr></thead>
    <?php
        $position=0; // we set the position as 0, as we start every loop with increasing it by one
        foreach ($results as $toppost) {
            $position++; // see, I told you, we increase by one, so the first post will get position #1
            echo "<tr><td>#".$plads."</td><td><a href='".get_permalink($toppost->ID)."'>".$toppost->title."</td><td>".round($toppost->total_votes)."</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php   
    }
?>
```

I already tried: `get_the_excerpt($toppost->title)` and `get_the_excerpt($toppost->ID)`, but none of them showed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for this anymore. You can use the **Template Builder** in the settings of GD-Star Rating self. Scroll to the bottom right if you have clicked on "Builder" and add a new template. Choose your own settings and paste the function or shortcode in your, respectively, page via the backend or page via Wordpress. Solved.

Comment: It is not immediately obvious what this means. Please add more detail to the answer.